# Общие папки ubuntu и Mac OSX в VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, macos, virtualbox

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста. Хост Ubuntu, гостевая Mac, возможно как-то открыть папку Ubunt-ы в Mac?

p.s. virtualbox guest additions в маке установлен, в VirtualBox папка добавлена. Но в маке она не отображается:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой.
guest additions не существует для OSX. А без guest additions папки не пробросить. НО можно использовать облачшые хранилища файлов типа dropbox.

Comment: Жаль(, спасибо!

Comment: Так же могу предложить решение-костыль.
На хостовой машине с Ubuntu разрешить доступ по ssh. А с гостевой машины OSX установить sshfs.
Для этого используйте [homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_ru.html).
`brew install sshfs`
А дальше подключить папку можно будет вот так:
`sshfs ubuntu@10.0.1.1:/var/www ~/my_sshfs_folder`
Папка куда мы хотим смонтировать, должна быть создана.
Что бы отмонтировать папку используй:
`sudo umount ~/my_sshfs_folder`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)